# Using Wordpress' WYSIWYG for comments

Tags: comments, tinymce, wysiwyg

I've been trying to set up the comments section of a site I am working on to use the default Wordpress WYSIWYG (TinyMCE). But it's harder than expected.

I used this [tutorial](http://www.revood.com/blog/tag/tinymce-wordpress-comments-box/) to take me almost all the way there. The tutorial makes it so I can use the WYSIWYG as the comment form, and it even has a fix when you click on a comment reply link (so that it will work there too).

The problem occurs when you click on a comment reply link, then cancel. This causes the original WYSIWYG (the one that first loads at the bottom of the comment stream) to break.

I have no idea how to make this WYSIWYG work again. Any thoughts or ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to hook into `wp_footer` instead of `wp_head`. Won't solve your problem, but makes sure other scripts are loaded before that.

Comment: Good question. I am trying to solve since i see i have same problem but i hope someone will find it before me :)

Answer (score 5):

Give this a shot:

```
<?php
/* Add WYSISYG editor to comment form. */
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'wpse_64243_comment_editor' );

function wpse_64243_comment_editor( $field ) {

    if (!is_single()) return $field; //only on single post pages.
    global $post;

    ob_start();

    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array(
        'textarea_rows' => 15
    ) );

    $editor = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    //make sure comment media is attached to parent post

    $editor = str_replace( 'post_id=0', 'post_id='.get_the_ID(), $editor );

    return $editor;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found solution. Basically you should remove all those additions from that tutorial and use "First solution for fixing comment-reply.js to support visual editors" section from http://www.techytalk.info/add-tinymce-quicktags-visual-editors-wordpress-comments-form/

I dont want copy-paste his solution here but we just creating a new comment-reply.js that supports wysiwyg

You can see live example with comments here: http://unsalkorkmaz.com/twitter-embeds-in-wrong-language/